# org.json.JSONException: No value for 0

Tags: android, android-asynctask, getjson

I'm getting response from an API.
But as soon as I get to the return command I get the following error:

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for 0
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getInt(JSONObject.java:478)
W/System.err:     at bobbydejong.expandabletest.OrderOverzicht.prepareOrderList(OrderOverzicht.java:65)
W/System.err:     at bobbydejong.expandabletest.OrderOverzicht$1.onSuccess(OrderOverzicht.java:37)
W/System.err:     at bobbydejong.expandabletest.GetOrderSwagger.onPostExecute(GetOrderSwagger.java:113)
W/System.err:     at bobbydejong.expandabletest.GetOrderSwagger.onPostExecute(GetOrderSwagger.java:21)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:660)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
```

It happens on this piece of code:

```
public class GetItemsSwagger extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
String result2;
private OnEventListener<String> mCallBack;
public Exception mException;
private Context context;
HttpURLConnection conn = null;
OutputStream os = null;
InputStream is = null;
String toastMsg = "Failed to get API response.";
String apiKey;




public GetItemsSwagger(Context context, OnEventListener callback) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mCallBack = callback;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {



    try {
        apiKey = strings[1];

        URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestProperty("apikey", apiKey);

        int status = conn.getResponseCode();

        if(status >= 400)
            is = conn.getErrorStream();
        else
            is = conn.getInputStream();


        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
        } else {
            toastMsg = "";
        }
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (is)));

        String output;
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            toastMsg += output;
        }

        conn.disconnect();



        result2= "";
        return toastMsg;
```

EDIT:

```
[{"orderGroupID":"1","name":"Patat","orderStatusID":"8","orderTo":"2017-02-24 11:15:00","created":"2017-02-24 10:04:21"},{"orderGroupID":"2","name":"Patat","orderStatusID":"8","orderTo":"2017-03-03 11:00:00","created":"2017-03-03 10:06:53"},{"orderGroupID":"3","name":"Patat","orderStatusID":"8","orderTo":"2017-03-10 11:10:00","created":"2017-03-10 10:27:32"},{"orderGroupID":"4","name":"Patat","orderStatusID":"8","orderTo":"2017-03-17 11:00:00","created":"2017-03-17 08:27:48"},{"orderGroupID":"5","name":"Patat","orderStatusID":"8","orderTo":"2017-03-24 11:00:00","created":"2017-03-24 08:58:08"},{"orderGroupID":"6","name":"Patat","orderStatusID":"8","orderTo":"2017-03-31 11:00:00","created":"2017-03-31 09:26:01"},{"orderGroupID":"7","name":"Patat","orderStatusID":"8","orderTo":"2017-04-07 11:00:00","created":"2017-04-07 10:02:52"},{"orderGroupID":"8","name":"Patat","orderStatusID":"8","orderTo":"2017-04-14 11:00:00","created":"2017-04-14 09:40:43"},{"orderGroupID":"9","name":"Patat","orderStatusID":"8","orderTo":"2017-04-21 11:00:00","created":"2017-04-21 10:01:31"},{"orderGroupID":"11","name":"Patat","orderStatusID":"8","orderTo":"2017-04-28 11:00:00","created":"2017-04-28 10:12:45"},{"orderGroupID":"12","name":"Patat","orderStatusID":"8","orderTo":"2017-05-05 11:00:00","created":"2017-05-05 09:39:56"},{"orderGroupID":"13","name":"Patat","orderStatusID":"8","orderTo":"2017-05-12 11:10:00","created":"2017-05-12 09:52:26"},{"orderGroupID":"14","name":"Patat","orderStatusID":"8","orderTo":"2017-05-19 11:00:00","created":"2017-05-19 09:58:37"}]
```

This is the JSON response

```
 try {
        JSONArray jObjArray = new JSONArray(orderResult);
        int length = jObjArray.length();
        final ArrayList<String> orderList = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

            HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
            JSONObject jObj = jObjArray.getJSONObject(i);
            map.put("orderGroupID", jObj.getInt("orderGroupID"));
            map.put("0", jObj.getInt("0"));
            map.put("name", jObj.getString("name"));
            map.put("orderStatusID", jObj.getInt("orderStatusID"));
            map.put("2", jObj.getInt("2"));
            map.put("orderTo", jObj.getString("orderTo"));
            map.put("3", jObj.getString("3"));
            map.put("created", jObj.getString("created"));


            String orderTo = jObj.getString("orderTo");
            String orderGroupID = jObj.getString("orderGroupID");


            orderList.add(orderTo+"   "+orderGroupID);
```

This is where I manipulate the code (different class)

I am looking forward to your response, I've been trying to find this problem on other posts but it seems those solutions don't workout for me and not quite the same problem. Correct me if I'm wrong but I'm a starter!

Comment: Post the JSON response that you receive and the code where you manipulate this response.

Comment: I added the requested code @PrerakSola

Comment: The lines `map.put("0", jObj.getInt("0"));`, `map.put("2", jObj.getInt("2"));`, `map.put("3", jObj.getInt("3"));` are invalid as there are no values with the keys 0, 2 or 3 in your JSON response.

Comment: You're trying to get an int with the key "0" at the line map.put("0", jObj.getInt("0")); but in the response there is no such key so it throws a jsonException

Comment: You are a genius... solved it in 3,5 min (I worked on this issue for 3,5 weeks...) thanks so much! @PrerakSola

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, "orderGroupID" value within your JSON response is a **String** and you are trying to access it via `jObj.getInt("orderGroupID"));`. You should access it using `jObj.getString("orderGroupID"));`

Second, there is not any Key with value "0" within your JSON response, so that parsing will throw and Exception.

Comment: Credits -> Prerak Sola (couldn't click solve on his name) This was the solution to my problem!

Answer (score 0):

As your `orderGroupID` value is `string`, just use `jObj.getString("orderGroupID")` instead of `jObj.getInt("orderGroupID")`.

**Try this:**

```
try {
    JSONArray jObjArray = new JSONArray(orderResult);
    int length = jObjArray.length();
    final ArrayList<String> orderList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        JSONObject jObj = jObjArray.getJSONObject(i);
        map.put("orderGroupID", jObj.getString("orderGroupID"));
        map.put("name", jObj.getString("name"));
        map.put("orderStatusID", jObj.getString("orderStatusID"));
        map.put("orderTo", jObj.getString("orderTo"));
        map.put("created", jObj.getString("created"));

        ..........
        .................
}
```